# Is there a way to determine when WebView has loaded the HTML? (so when the DOM is ready)

Tags: android, dom, webview, domready

I'd like the inject javascript into the WebView as soon as the HTML is loaded and the DOM is ready, so not waiting for the all assets.

I know about `onPageFinished`, but it is called when everything is loaded. I'd like a callback sooner when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by injecting a javascript event listener in `onPageStarted`:

```
web.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                view.loadUrl("javascript:document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { <your stuff> })");

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a JS lisntener interface on the WebView, and call it in `onload` in your HTML

Here's an [example](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)

**EDIT**

Since you mentioned you cannot modify the HTML, try this:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(context));

private final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        if (newProgress == 100){
           // loading done
        }
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wanted to try it, but now I see you mean modifying the HTML. I can't, it's an external page I don't control, so I can't add anything to html.

Comment: updated my answer, let me know if it solves your issue